# How do I generate a list of async computed results without blocking?

Tags: f#

How do I generate a list of async computed results without blocking?

**I have the following code:**

```
    async {

        let! result1 = requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-eta"               
        let! result2 = requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.customer-cancelled"        
        let! result3 = requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-cancelled"         
        let! result4 = requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-arrived-at-pickup" 
        let! result6 = requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-enroute-to-dropoff"
        let! result7 = requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-arrived-at-dropoff"
        let! result8 = requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-dropped-off"       
        let! result9 = requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-arrived-at-pickup" 

        let errorOccurred = // I want to avoid this...
            [result1
             result2
             result3
             result4
             result6
             result7
             result8
             result9
            ] |> List.forall(fun x -> x |> function | Error _ -> false | Ok _ -> true)

        return
            if not errorOccurred
            then Ok ()
            else Error "Failed to create all topics"
    }
```

**Here's a workaround that blocks:**

```
    async {

        return

            [requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-eta"                |> Async.RunSynchronously
             requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.customer-cancelled"         |> Async.RunSynchronously
             requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-cancelled"          |> Async.RunSynchronously
             requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-arrived-at-pickup"  |> Async.RunSynchronously
             requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-enroute-to-dropoff" |> Async.RunSynchronously
             requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-arrived-at-dropoff" |> Async.RunSynchronously
             requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-dropped-off"        |> Async.RunSynchronously
             requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-arrived-at-pickup"  |> Async.RunSynchronously

            ] |> List.forall(fun x -> x |> function | Error _ -> false | Ok _ -> true)
              |> function
                 | false -> Error "Failed to create all topics"
                 | true  -> Ok ()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Async.Parallel`:

```
let! results = 
    [
        requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.courier-eta" 
        requestId |> createTopicAsync "Topic.customer-cancelled"
        ...
    ] |> Async.Parallel

results |> Array.forAll ...
```

Note that the result will be Array, not List